# Не могу создать поиск в Libre office base

Tags: sql, postgresql, libre-office

Я хочу создать форму в Libre Office Base, в которой бы присутствовало поле, играющее роль поиска. То есть если я напишу туда запрос, то поле выполнит поиск по заранее определённому столбцу в определённой таблице.

У меня практически это получилось. Я написал такой запрос:

```
select cd.course_code, cd.faculty, cd.lector, cd.student, cd.student_email, cd.yt_list,  cd.looking_t, cd.time_period, cd.course_name 
from "public".courses_d cd 
where (upper(cd.faculty) like upper( :Search_F ))
```

Этот запрос вызывает окошко перед каждым запуском формы, где просит указать значение этой переменной и если вводить туда искомое, то всё работает как надо.

Проблема собственно в том, что я не могу назначить на поле переменную Search_F. Где я только не искал как обращаться к содержимому поля - не нашёл.
Граждане из интернета создают поисковые таблицы, в которые вносит изменения поле поиска, а потом используют эти таблицы в запросе. Но это, извините меня, костыли какие-то. Неужели нельзя как-то извлечь содержимое поля в переменную?
Помогите пожалуйста. Уже неделю мучаюсь.